# Login Issue with ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor server app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor Server App. I am using Microsoft Identity Framework Core for authorization. It loads menu items after successful user login only. I have used the following authorisation scenario on both `NavMenu.razor` and `Home.razor` components.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        ........
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <Components.Account.Pages.Login>

        </Components.Account.Pages.Login>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

When app loads, it asks for login. At successful login, it displays the menu items in the `sidebar`. When I perform a submit operation on any of the pages, all the menu items disappear and it displays the login page again.

Here is my `program.cs` code:

```
using GetTutorsOnline.Components;
using GetTutorsOnline.Components.Account;
using GetTutorsOnline.Data;
using GTO.IModels.IModelRepos;
using GTO.Infrastructure.Data;
using GTO.Infrastructure.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
    .AddIdentityCookies();

var conStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DifriPediaSQLDb");
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<GTODbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conStr));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conStr));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<GTOAppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<GTOAppUser>, IdentityNoOpEmailSender>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubjectNameRepo, SubjectNameRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRegionRepo, RegionRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAssessmentMonthRepo, AssessmentMonthRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IELevelRepo, ELevelRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITeacherRepo, TeacherRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICoordinatorRepo, CoordinatorRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IManagerRepo, ManagerRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStudentRepo, StudentRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IParentRepo, ParentRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEvaluationTweekRepo, EvaluationTweekRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubjectAllocationRepo, SubjectAllocationRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDayNameRepo, DayNameRepo>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

//app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.Run();
```

Below is the code of `IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider` class

```
using GetTutorsOnline.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace GetTutorsOnline.Components.Account
{
    // This is a server-side AuthenticationStateProvider that revalidates the security stamp for the connected user
    // every 30 minutes an interactive circuit is connected.
    internal sealed class IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider(
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> options)
        : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider(loggerFactory)
    {
        protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

        protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
            AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
            await using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<GTOAppUser>>();
            return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
        }

        private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<GTOAppUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
            if (user is null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(options.Value.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
                var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
                return principalStamp == userStamp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider` do?

Comment: This is a server-side AuthenticationStateProvider that revalidates the security stamp for the connected user every 30 minutes an interactive circuit is connected. I have added its code too, in the main question.

Comment: I usually find making sure to say to inject the authenticationstateprovider on each page takes care of this kind of issue.